# Error when reading from file

Tags: python, file-io

I am trying to parse the contents of a file in a list line by line in python. I am new to python so I can't understand what I am doing wrong. Here is my code so far:

```
ins = open( "input.txt", "r" )
array = []
for line in ins:
    array.append( line )
ins.close()   
print array
```

I get the following error

```
array.append( line )
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Comment: `with open("input.txt") as f: array = f.readlines()`. But getting back to your original question, did you perhaps mix tabs and spaces in the input?

Comment: Apparently you aren't doing anything wrong. The problem is with the indentation. Is this line correctly 4 spaces indented `array.append(line)`?

Comment: Is that your exact code, copy-pasted into the question?  Is it possible that your original code doesn't have the `array.append` line indented?

Comment: Can't reproduce this. Indentation is important in python make sure your code is exactly the same as one you've pasted here.

Comment: looks good to me, indentation is correct when i copy paste.

Comment: @larsmans I try not to mix them

Comment: @RichieHindle I copied and pasted everything and checked for differences between tabs and space with the original and it seems the same to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried this out and it seems to work, remember that Python is rather strict about indentation. The recommended PEP8 standard is to use 4 spaces between layers of indentation. Don't mix tabs and spaces as this can confuse the Python interpreter.

If you don't already have it, get yourself [PyLint](http://www.pylint.org/) as it can detect these kind of syntax issues rather easily.